# C# - How to replace a list or property values within a List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have binded a control with a BindingList `dataSource`. Let's say:

```
var dataSource = new List<Model>()
{
   new Model()
   {
      Name = "A",
      CostValue = 60
   },
   new Model()
   {
      Name = "B",
      CostValue = 0
   }
};
```

And whenever there is a property change, it will trigger a third party method that recalculates the `CostValue` and returns a new list of `CostValues` like:

```
var newCostValue = new List<double>(){40,0};
```

So what is the best way to replace the `CostValue` list within the `dataSource` bindinglist with the new `CostValue`, since there might be lots of models inside the dataSource bindinglist, with two `foreach` loop would be really slow.

I have tried to find the difference between the two lists, but with no luck. It seems that by getting the `costValue` using SELECT, the Except function just don't work, why is that?

```
 var list11 = dataSource.Select(x => x.CostValue).ToList();//If we create a new list with just values, the Except would work
 var newCostValue = new List<double>() {60,0};
 var dif = list11.Except(newCostValue).ToList();//Getting None, why is that?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type of Model.CostValue?

Comment: why not assigning new value list as datasource?

Comment: @Damith what happens if the model will contain more fields or the reference is important, this is bad practice i think

Answer (score 0):

You need to [implement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatablet-you-still-must-override-objects-equals-and-gethashcode/) IEquatable, so the items can be compared for equality.

Comment: Hi @qub1n, thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to implement IEquatable, but with no success. The CostValueComparer just won't be called. But if I create two dummy List<double>, this comparer will be executed. What's the difference between a linq select list<double> and a generic List<double>?

Comment: Provide comparer is not enough, your Model need to implement IEquatable interface and override GetHashCode. What interface your Model implement?

Comment: public class Model:IEquatable<Model>
    {
        public string Serie { get; set; }
        public string RowName { get; set; }
        public double CostValue { get; set; }
        public bool Equals(Model other)
        {
            return other != null && Serie.Equals(other.Serie) && RowName.Equals(other.RowName);
        }
    }

Comment: And this comparer: public class CostValueComparer : IEqualityComparer<double>
    {
        public bool Equals(double x, double y)
        {
            return Math.Abs(x - y) < 1E-8;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(double obj)
        {
            unchecked 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CostValue HashCode: " + obj.GetHashCode());
                return obj.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you if you are also getting the name.

```
dataSource.First(d => d.Name == "B").CostValue = newCostValue[1];
```

but another one could be

```
dataSource.First(d => d.CostValue == newCostValue[0]).CostValue = newCostValue[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer a better answer which envolve more thread safety here.
Since items can be deleted, I assume, and assuming that the field `Name` is mapped uniquly to a price:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name;
    public double CostValue;
}

public List<Model> dataSource = new List<Model>()
    {
        new Model()
        {
            Name = "A",
            CostValue = 60
        },
        new Model()
        {
            Name = "B",
            CostValue = 0
        }
    };

/// <summary>
/// Updates the original dataSource with the new prices
/// </summary>
/// <param name="newPrices">Dictionary whereas the Keys are names and values are CostValue of an item</param>
public void PriceChange(Dictionary<string, double> newPrices)
{
    foreach (Model model in dataSource)
    {
        if (newPrices.ContainsKey(model.Name))
            model.CostValue = newPrices[model.Name];
    }
}
```

Thus, the update will cost an `O(n)` run time whereas `n` is the number of items in `dataSource` and of course is more safe to rely on the item name itself rather than its index in the list.

Why?

Because if you have another thread deleting items or modifies them so their index has changed, you gonna have a serious problem, you will update different items from what you wanted.

All you have to change is to return a new price dictionary rather than a `List<double>`

Comment: Hi @Ori Refael, thanks for your suggestion. Since the new Prices are provided by a third party dll, it won't be that easy to ask them to alter their schema, but I will give a try, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Spencer I would still advise you to keep a mapping (dictionary<int, string>) which is stored prior to the request so when the response is returned, you can get the model's Name from the dictionary (which holds index -> Name) and than go with that name and the value to update the price.